# React: multiple if statement in componentDidUpdate with await async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

in this code snippet:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.alpha != prevProps.alpha) {
       let one = await oneFoo();
    }
    if(this.props.beta != prevProps.beta) {
       let two = await twoFoo();
    }
}
```

if the alpha props changes, the second if wont be called until the first await is resolved.
Can this create some problem?
For example, while the first await is still computing, the beta props changes. So the first componentDidUpdate will call the second if after the await finishes but with a different beta props. Can this create problems?

Comment: Yes, it could be a problem: https://jsbin.com/lihemilavi/1/edit?js,console Slightly contrived example but it gets the point across. Same thing could happen if `this.props` changes.